# Set Background Opacity in Popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

i have a problem with my popup i want the background to be transparent but when i set opacity in css to 0.5 or less the text also is transparent and very dark.
How can i set the background to 50% opacity but the text is still 100%?
Help would be nice :)

Heres the full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwbmdw2g/

Here the html:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModall" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog imp-bg">
                        <div class="modal-content imp-bg">

                          <div class="modal-header imp-bg">
                            <div class="title">
                                <div></div>
                                News
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 imp-block">

                                    <p class="mini imp-mini">

                                    <strong>Hier steht der News Text.</strong><br />

                                    <br /><br />
                                    </p>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default imp-button" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Here the modal opening as requested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#myModall').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you want the background to be transparent you can use `rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` and it won't affect the text

Comment: already tried that but doesn't work

Comment: Where is the HTML code/element where you trigger the opening of the modal? Is it possible to include that code as well please?

Comment: added the opening script to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Albzi mentioned using rgba works. Change your imp-bg style to this.

```
.imp-bg{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}
```

Comment: works i forgot to delete the opacity:0.5 after background.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I thing it will help u. set your background opacity according to your need.

```
#myModall { background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="modal-dialog imp-bg">
```

```css
.modal-dialog imp-bg
{
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}
```